# Non-finite clause or to-infinitive?

Tags: complex-sentences, nonfinite-verbs, finite-verbs

I'm analysing this sentence complex in terms of sentence trees and am a bit at a loss here.

> He began to swim again, feeling suddenly the desperate exhaustion of his body.

In the part "He began to swim again," is the "to swim again" a nonfinite clause or just a bare infinitive? 
Do I write the tree as S --- Cl1 (He began) and then two subordinate semi-clauses Cl2 (to swim again) Cl3 (feeling suddenly....)

OR

Is it Main clause (He began to swim again) with one subordinate nonfinite clause (feeling suddenly...)?

Comment: You can use either an infinitive *(He began **to cry**)* or a continuous verb form *(He began **crying**)* in contexts such as yours. But this sort of question belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you looked up the term *bare infinitive*? It means an infinitive without the *to*.

Comment: "To swim again" is a to infinitival clause. Infinitival clauses are non-finite. I'd analyse the entire sentence as the matrix clause with the subordinate embedded "feeling" clause as a depictive adjunct giving descriptive information about the referent of the subject "he".

Comment: You're contrasting things that don't actually contrast. All infinitives are non-finite clauses, whether they appear with _to_ or not. "Non-finite" is what _infinitive_ **means**. A "bare infinitive" is an infinitive clause without a subject NP, which can be called a phrase if desired; there's still an implied subject, like _you_ in imperatives, and there's sometimes other implied NPs, depending on context, construction, and predicate choices. And the same applies to the non-finite participle _feeling_, which    relates to your original question.

Comment: The term "bare infinitival clause" has nothing to with the absence of a subject (an infinitival clause without a subject is simply called 'subjectless'). It's called "bare" because it lacks the marker _to_. See here: [link](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/glossary/b.htm) and here [link](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/clauses/bare.htm).Those infinitival clauses that do have the _to_ marker are called _to_ infinitivals.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. "He began" has a subject and verb - independent clause. It can be said by itself.

- "to swim" is non-finite clause - dependent clause
- "Feeling suddenly ..." is another non-finite clause - dependent clause

The question to ask when distinguishing a dependent and independent is whether there is a subject.

- Is there a subject next to the verb?
- Also, can that part of the sentence exist by itself i.e. be independent. "He began" ,although awkward, does makes sense, but "to swim" and "feeling suddenly..." cannot

In particular "to any verb" e.g. to swim, to run, are always dependent. They are timeless and need to go with something.

Another example:

**He wondered** whether **to go** to the beach, **looking** at the clouds.

Answer (score -4):

(He began) is the main clause and (to swim again) is an independent clause.

Comment: This is multiply wrong. There's only one finite verb in the sentence – *began* – so there's only one main clause. In a sentence with only one finite clause, the main clause is always an independent clause. The verb phrase *to swim again* is an **infinitival** clause, which is a type of a non-finite clause.